# Can a site I browse in private browsing mode tell if I visited it in regular mode before?

Tags: web-browser, privacy

I've noticed when updating a blog, that sometimes refreshing the page won't actually fetch it again, because it is still in the cache. Now, even when I open it in incognito in that same browser(say Chrome), it still uses the same cache, at least for some time. My understanding is that the site can "tell" my computer how long to store the page before fetching it again. So, say I set up a site that dynamically puts in the time and date, (or a unique code), into the page in a hidden field, and on loading, sends that back to me using Javascript or whatever. So I can tell if my site was browsed before by checking when I sent that code or what the time is, even though the browser is now in privacy mode.

Would this work, and if not, why not?

Comment: At minimum it sees your IP. But there are other fingerprinting techniques, for example screen resolution, installed fonts,...

Comment: Some info here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=275071

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** and this is by design:

> The point of incognito mode is not to prevent server side tracking. The whole design is about not leaking information on the client (about visited sites).

This comes from the Chromium team - look at [Comment #8](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=275071) I believe other browsers work similarly.

Some of the ways a site could do this:

- ETags - these are cache directives. If the page has been cached in normal mode, then these cache entries are available in incognito mode.
- IP address
- Browser fingerprint - screen resolution, installed plugins, etc.

You may be able to get better privacy by using [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) in combination with incognito mode.

Comment: This *is* **leaking information on the client about visited sites**. The website can tell if I have visited it in my browser without privacy mode. And it might even be able to see other sites via hidden frames or whatever

Comment: @ike In which direction is it leaking information? From normal to incognito, or the other way round?

Comment: From normal to incognito.

Comment: @ike leaks from normal to incognito are allowed - this is made obvious because you have your normal address bar history available in incognito mode. If you find a leak the other way then you should definitely report it to the Chromium team.

Comment: I don't think so, **I** as a user can access history in Incognito mode, but the website can't. My method would allow them to.

Comment: @paj28 With most browsers, private browsing starts with a clean and empty cache, so etags can't jump the gap. Also, in certain browsers the plugin list will be different.

Comment: @ike Chrome is clear up-front that incognito doesn't protect you from server tracking. If you need more privacy than this you need to take further steps, perhaps the ToR Browser Bundle.